# Java sorting a list of integers excluding a specific value

Tags: java, list, sorting, integer

Here is my problem:
I have a list of integers: `7,0,2`
If I sort the list using `Collections.sort(list)` the result is: `0,2,7`
but I want to sort the list excluding the `0` from the sorting procedure so the output looks like this: `2,0,7`.
Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've forgot to mention my 3 possible cases:
1) list contains only one "0" and two numbers
2) list contains two "0" and one number
3) list contains three "0" and no numbers

Comment: Do you only want to only exclude all the 0 ? What's happen with 7, 18, 0, 9, 1, 0 ?

Comment: Only a suggestion, as there isn't much code to correct: Use `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` with a `Comparator` that consideres `0` equal to everything and otherwise behaves just 'normal'. As `Collections.sort` guarantees to be *stable*, it should not move any `0`.

Comment: @lzruo Doesn't it depend on the sorting algorithm? Stable only means that two *equal items* are in the same order as pre-sort, not that generally items do not move.

Comment: @ReutSharabani It's important to note that `0` should be equal to **everything**. So it won't change place with anything, hence remain where it initially was.

Comment: @Izruo _with a Comparator that consideres 0 equal to everything and otherwise behaves just 'normal'_ It's an awful idea. there are some cases when It wouldn't sort anything.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Yes I see now, it's for example `1 == 0 == 2   <=/=>   1 < 2`. I guess we cannot rely on the algorithm to check both.

Comment: @Izruo: such a comparator will violate an explicit rule. The javadoc for `int Comparator.compare(T o1, To2)` states *Finally, the implementor must ensure that compare(x, y)==0 implies that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z.*. That is not true if x is 0 and y is not. So you cannot be sure of what `sort` will do with this comparator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it but not only with `Collections.sort()`

1. Retrieve and store in a variable the index where the `0` Integer is :
2. Remove the `0` from the List with `List.remove(int)` where `int` is the index.
3. Sort the list with `Collections.sort()`
4. Add `0` in the List at the stored index.

In code, it gives :

```
List<Integer> list = ...;
int indexOf = list.indexOf(Integer.valueOf(0));
list.remove(indexOf);
Collections.sort(list);
list.add(indexOf, Integer.valueOf(0));
```

---

Update after question edit to handle cases with more than one `0` in the List.

I updated because this case is a little more complex to handle.
As it removes more than one element, the index is not any longer the index of the original size.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(7);
    list.add(0);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(9);
    list.add(0);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(0);
    list.add(4);

    Set<Integer> indexesOf = new HashSet<>();
    int indexOf = -1;
    int shift = 0;
    while ((indexOf = list.indexOf(Integer.valueOf(0))) != -1) {
        indexesOf.add(indexOf + shift++);
        list.remove(indexOf);
    }

    Collections.sort(list);
    indexesOf.stream().forEach(index -> list.add(index, Integer.valueOf(0)));
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Output :

> [1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 7, 0, 9]

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort it's your friend!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(7, 0, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        int a = list.get(i);            
        for (int j = i + 1; a != 0 && j < list.size(); j++) {
            int b = list.get(j);
            if (b != 0 && b < a){
                list.set(i, b);
                list.set(j, a);
                a = b; // EDITED
            }
        }    
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: I've actually wrote a unit test for your sort and it does not seem to work on larger lists and multiple 0's.

Comment: @skubski please, could you share your unit test? pastebin or wherever you want

Comment: The OP reformulated his question and reposed it in a comment. It seems to be deleted now. Unit test with a larger list containing two zeros fails, see [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/JCcnrxms).

Comment: @skubski Thank you, I saw the mistake, and I've edited.